# ValueError: Only support a single signature key

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a tensorflow 2.0 project and while saving my model and attempting to convert to tensorflow lite format, I encountered this error.

```
saved_decoder2=tf.saved_model.save(decoder, "C:\\Users\\...\\saved_model_for_decoder")
converter2 = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("C:\\Users\\...\\saved_model_for_decoder", signature_keys=None)
tflite_model2 = converter2.convert()
open("decoder.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model2)
```

The error said:

> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:/Users/user.../Image-Captioning_using_Tensorflow.py", line 323, in
>
> converter2 = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("C:\Users\...\saved_model_for_decoder",
> signature_keys=None)   File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py",
> line 1033, in from_saved_model
> raise ValueError("Only support a single signature key.") ValueError: Only support a single signature key.*

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please load the saved_model and print the signatures and see whether it contains several signatures? If so, please specify one signature.

```
imported = tf.saved_model.load(path)
print(imported.signatures)
```